# Google Maps API Error: This API key is not authorized to use this service or API. Places API error: ApiTargetBlockedMapError

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wagtail

I've started getting this error from a Google Maps widget within a CMS I use:

`This API key is not authorized to use this service or API. Places API error: ApiTargetBlockedMapError`

The error message [provides a helpful link to this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-target-blocked-map-error), which includes the following text:

> ApiTargetBlockedMapError  Error
>
> The Maps JavaScript API has not been authorized for the used API key.
>   Please check the API restrictions settings of your API key in the
>   Google Cloud Platform Console.
>
> See API keys in the Google Cloud Platform Console. For more
>   information, see Using API Keys.

I know Google has tweaked this API in the past, so I went to the console and checked the permissions given for the key I am using. It includes these four permissions, include the Maps JavaScript API permission:

- Geocoding API
- Maps Embed API
- Maps JavaScript API
- Maps Static API

The only part not working is the address auto-complete. When I change to `Don't Restrict Key` mode so the key works with all services, it works fine. Any idea which service checkbox I might be missing? I'm wondering if Google is just displaying the wrong error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I did. Updated.

1. Make sure you have enabled all the next Google Maps Services
   [image]
2. If you have key restrictions, make sure you add the services like the next image.[image].
3. Restart the project. It worked.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Key Restrictions!

Comment: It would be nice if the error said which API the key is trying to access...

Comment: that's fine, this solution save my day

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that Google has tweaked their permissions settings without updating the error. I had to give access to the `Places API` as well for the autocomplete to function.

I've submitted a PR to the CMS widget's documentation:
https://github.com/Frojd/wagtail-geo-widget/pull/59/files

Comment: Same. Thanks for mentioning.